# Python permission error unskippable

Tags: python-3.x, antivirus

I'm trying to make an antivirus in python, but I keep getting a permissions denied error when i get its hash and check even when I make it ignore the error and try and move on to the next file to hash and check. I'm fine with the error, but I'm trying it to make it move to the next file and nothing I try works. I'm using windows.

## AV.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import os
import sys
import time
import glob
import simple_hasher
from colorama import *
init()

#Begin code

#variable_set
virlfile = "ListFile.hash"
vircount = 0
virusdel = []
hashtype = "MD5"
#variable_end

#fileloadhash
if not os.path.isfile(virlfile):
    try:
        with open(virlfile, "w") as f:
            f.close
    except IOError as err:
        print("Error, Something went WRONG!")
        print("Error as reported:")
        print("{}".format(err))

with open(virlfile) as f:
    data = f.read()
#scanner

filecount = 0
try:
    for file in glob.glob("./**/*", recursive = True):
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            file_hash = simple_hasher.get_hash(file, hashtype)
            if file_hash in data:
                print("{} | {}".format(file_hash, Fore.CYAN + file + " (!)ALERT" + Style.RESET_ALL))
                vircount += 1
                virusdel.append(file)
                filecount += 1
            else:
                print("{} | {}".format(file_hash, file))
                filecount += 1
except OSError:
    pass

if vircount > 0:
    print("\n{} Viruses Detected. Delete? Y/N".format(vircount))

    try:
        choice = input(">> ").lower().split(" ")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("SCAN ABORTED!")

    try:
        if choice[0] == "y":
            for file in virusdel:
                try:
                    os.remove(file)
                    print("File Deleted - {}".format(os.path.abspath(file)))
                except Exception as err:
                    print ("Unable to remove file.\n{}".format(err))

            print("\n(+) All Viruses Removed.\n")
        else:
            sys.exit()
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error: {}".format(err))
else:
    print("\n(+)No viruses\n")
    sys.exit()
```

I also have a custom module being imported:

## simple_hasher.py

```
import hashlib
import os
import sys

def get_hash(file, ver):
    if ver.lower() == "md5":
        h = hashlib.md5()
    elif ver.lower() == "sha1":
        h = hashlib.sha1()
    elif ver.lower() == "sha256":
        h = hashlib.sha256()
    else:
        h = hashlib.sha1()
    while not False:
        try:
            with open(file, "rb") as f:
                while True:
                    data = f.read(2 ** 20)
                    if not data: break
                    h.update(data)
                return h.hexdigest()
        except Exception as err:
            print("[Debug] [{}] - Message: {}".format(os.path.split(__file__)[1], err))
            pass
```

The error:

```
[Debug] [simple_hasher.py] - Message: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.\\hiberfil.sys'
```

Comment: Fire up a debugger session. Find why your while loop breaks

Comment: Which file would need debugging?